# how to track adsense and remove it in my web

Tags: adsense, googleads-mobile-unity

can someone explain to me how to track google ads in my website ? and also how to remove him.
i've checked all source code in my web but everything is clean code (no adsense script).
this ads only appears in mobile view, but when i check in google chrome in my PC there is an adsense script in chrome inspect.

here's screenshot in google chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Search for that *integrator.js* file in your codebase, as that's where the ads are originating.

Comment: i've check all source code is clean, no file integrator.js